# PHP mssql_fetch_field not returning column_source

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I run a query with a few joins using mssql_query()

I then have something like:

```
$fields = mssql_num_fields($result);
```

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-field.php
$fields[i] should have a property called column_source containing the table name the field is from. Oddly column_source is the name of the field, not the name of the table it's from.

```
column_source: "projectItemsID"
max_length: 4
name: "projectItemsID"
numeric: 1
type: "int"
```

As you can see, name and column_source are the same.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like a bug, or a mistake in the documentation.  Reading through the comments in the documentation, a lot of other people have found the same thing  :/

Comment: @CullyLarson, would you happen to know another library I can use to get the column source from a field? ODBC doesn't seem to provide it.

Comment: If you're creating the query yourself, don't you already know which table each field is coming from?

Comment: @CullyLarson I'm not writing the queries. I am building an internal web based DB Admin tool. I would like to display the results with the column name and the table it's from. Ideally... I would also like to build inline field editing from the browser. To do this I need the table the field is from and primary key info (which I can already get).